# Mongodb, finding matches with text search in multiple fields

Tags: mongodb

I have documents which have first_name, last_name, id_no and phone fields.

I want to make text search to retrieve documents which contain one or more of the search terms.

For example:

```
{"$text":{"$search":"JOHN YES"}}
```

retrieves all documents that contain JOHN or YES in any indexed fields.

But

```
{"$text":{"$search":" \"JOHN\"  \"YES\" "}}
```

retrieves exactly the document whose first_name exactly JOHN and last_name exactly YES

But

```
{"$text":{"$search":" \" JOHN YES \" "}}
```

Doesn't response anything because any field  has exactly JOHN YES

Since I won't know which part is related to which field, I can't use this.

What I want is that if I query like this:

```
"JOHN YES SOMEID_NO"
```

It should returns, documents that contains one or more words of those search term in any fields.

Example results:

```
1. first_name: JOHN
2. first_name JOHN YES
3. first_name JOHN, last_name YES
4. id_no: SOMEID_NO
5. first_name: YES
```

or similar combinations..

Answer (score 0):

By including quotation marks, you're searching for the exact phrase within quotation marks. Including whitespace.

You're searching for `" JOHN YES "`, with a space at the beginning and at the end. That text search will only match documents where any field contains `" JOHN YES "`, including those spaces.

Comment: Is there a way to change this behavior? This is not the behavior of almost every other search engine out there.